# AWS CDK: RuntimeError: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'region')

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I am deploying a CDK stack with an AWS codepipeline. Nevertheless, I get an error I cannot interpret.

```
#######################################################
############### DEPLOY CODE PIPELINE ##################
#######################################################

print("Deploy Code Pipeline:", project_name_clean)
        
# Create a CodePipeline
pipeline = codepipeline.Pipeline(
   self,
   f'CodePipeline_{project_name_clean}',
   pipeline_name=f'codepipeline_{project_name_clean}',
)

# Add the CodeCommit source stage to the pipeline
source_stage = pipeline.add_stage(
   stage_name='Source',
)
source_action = codepipeline_actions.CodeCommitSourceAction(
   action_name='SourceAction',
   repository=repository,
   # branch='master',
   output=codepipeline.Artifact()
)
source_stage.add_action(source_action)

# Add the CodeBuild build stage to the pipeline
build_stage = pipeline.add_stage(
   stage_name='Build',
)
build_action = codepipeline_actions.CodeBuildAction(
   action_name='BuildAction',
   project=codebuild_project,
   input=codepipeline.Artifact(),
)
build_stage.add_action(build_action)
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/glue_user/workspace/jupyter_workspace/repositories/aws-infrastructure/cdk-constructs/app_cdk_initialize_project/app.py", line 20, in <module>
    InitializeProjectStack(app, f"{stack_name_clean}")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jsii/_runtime.py", line 112, in __call__
    inst = super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/glue_user/workspace/jupyter_workspace/repositories/aws-infrastructure/cdk-constructs/otd_data_engineer_lib/otd_data_engineer_lib/initialize_project_stack.py", line 249, in __init__
    build_stage.add_action(build_action)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aws_cdk/aws_codepipeline/__init__.py", line 5815, in add_action
    return typing.cast(None, jsii.invoke(self, "addAction", [action]))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jsii/_kernel/__init__.py", line 149, in wrapped
    return _recursize_dereference(kernel, fn(kernel, *args, **kwargs))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jsii/_kernel/__init__.py", line 399, in invoke
    response = self.provider.invoke(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jsii/_kernel/providers/process.py", line 377, in invoke
    return self._process.send(request, InvokeResponse)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jsii/_kernel/providers/process.py", line 339, in send
    raise RuntimeError(resp.error) from JavaScriptError(resp.stack)
RuntimeError: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'region')
```

Comment: most probably its due to either context or the way you are deploying ( credentials error)